# Java rest testing with rest-assured multiple GET requests

Tags: java, rest, security, testing, rest-assured

I have a Spring-boot application and it's a REST service for my AngularJS app.
I'm trying to write some unit tests for it, and this is sample code from one of it.

```
    given().
            auth().basic(USER_LOGIN, "X").
            get("http://myservice/login").
            then().assertThat().statusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
    given().
            auth().basic(USER_LOGIN, PASSWORD).
            get("http://myservice/login").
            then().assertThat().statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
```

The problem is that my second assertion is not passed. But when I'm trying to swap their places, assertion with UNAUTHORIZED status not passing. If I'll try to reproduce this test case with SoapUI, it will work fine, both assertions are done. Probably, it's caching results of requests somehow?

p.s. The security provider I'm using is Spring security.

Comment: Look at this ticket(https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2976) to see if it's the same problem.

Comment: looks like this is not the case. thanks:)

Comment: Have you read this discussion(https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-issues/issues/36) that was mentioned on the description of the jira ticket?

Comment: @AndreyS, did you solve your problem? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset to the standard baseURI (localhost), basePath (empty), standard port (8080), default authentication scheme (none) and default root path (empty string) using:
 RestAssured.reset();

https://rest-assured.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/apidocs/index.html?com/jayway/restassured/RestAssured.html - Search for reset method in documentation.